# How to specify order of fields inside a composed primary key?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa-2.1

This question is about ordering inside a composed index, which is a more specific problem than ordering columns inside a table.

I have a simple class with a composed id:

```
@Embeddable
class PrimaryKeyClass {
    private int a;
    private int b;
}

@Entity
class SimpleClassWithComposedId {
    @EmbeddedId
    PrimaryKeyClass id;
}
```

It seems like hibernate is generating the primary key with the fields ordered by lexicographical order, at least it was what happened in my tests cases. But i would like to know if there is a way to specify the order of the fields in the primary key, because this is very important since we can heavily optmize queries that use a prefix of the composed index ( i have read this in the [postgres docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/indexes-multicolumn.html) )

Answer (score 1):

One option would be to rename the columns in the table in the lexical order.

Alternatively, does adding a `Column` name help?

```java
@Column(name = "a")
private int k_2a;

@Column(name = "b")
private int k_1a;
```

Comment: I have done some more testing, and what happened is that hibernate takes into consideration the field name not the name inside the @Column. This is sad.

Comment: @krionz, Oh ok. So, changing the table column names seems to be the only possible option.(need to take care of any other existing clients reading directly from table)

Comment: @krionz, one last suggestion, have you tried adding the java class attributes in different order along with name change and @Column annotation.  Something like ```@Column(name = "b")
private int k_1a; @Column(name = "a")
private int k_2a;
``` Not sure whether this will work, please give it a try, if you haven't already. Do update when you found a working solution without updating the table column names. Thank you and all the best

Comment: Yes, it works because of the nane change, but not because of the order of the attributes inside the class or names inside @Column annotation. I think i will change the name of the entity properties. Thank you.

Comment: @krionz, thank you for sharing the result.